# Scraping using Beautifulsoup, extracting text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract " ₹ 75" from below line.

```
<td class="srpTuple__midGrid title_semiBold srpTuple__spacer16 " id="srp_tuple_price">₹ 75
```

I am trying to extract " ₹ 75". Can anyone please help? :)

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @sureshmani i used this::

rows=tags.findAll('td')
for row in rows:
    if row.get('id',None)=='srp_tuple_price':

Comment: @Sureshmani `rows=tags.findAll('td')
for row in rows:
    if row.get('id',None)=='srp_tuple_price':
`
but struck after this!! :(

Comment: if you try to extract the value of the element, then row.text should be used. see my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it to get the price `₹ 75`:
For single `td` element:

```
html_doc = """<td class="srpTuple__midGrid title_semiBold srpTuple__spacer16 " id="srp_tuple_price">₹ 75</td"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

price = price = soup.find('td', id="srp_tuple_price").text

print(price)
```

For multipule `td` element:

```
html_doc = """<td class="srpTuple__midGrid title_semiBold srpTuple__spacer16 " id="srp_tuple_price">₹ 75</td"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

prices = soup.find_all('td', id="srp_tuple_price")

for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the value and compare it against a variable,

```
srp_tuple_price = '₹ 75'
html = '<td class="srpTuple__midGrid title_semiBold srpTuple__spacer16 " id="srp_tuple_price">₹ 75</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')

rows=soup.findAll('td')
for row in rows: 
    if row.text==srp_tuple_price:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print ('fail')
```

**Output:**
Success